# How to know when FindRoot[] fails to find a solution

Tags: equation-solving, programming

My problem is very simple. Assume you have this piece of code :

```
FindRoot[{x^2 + 1 == 0}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

Now, this code returns

```
FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
{x -> -1.}
```

Which is as expected since the equation has no real root. Now my question is, how can I get the fact that FindRoot failed in a variable ? Say I want to display a message "Failed search", when FindRoot fails for whatever reason, how do I collect the fact that the function failed ? I was looking into `Catch[]`, but it seems that no exception is thrown.

Comment: See [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check)

Comment: Works great, thanks !

Comment: `FindRoot` can find complex roots if you tell it to look in the complex plane, e.g., `FindRoot[{x^2 + 1 == 0}, {x, -1 + I, 1 + I}]` evaluates to `{x -> 1.16068*10^-19 + 1. I}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand [@Carl's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236291/how-to-know-when-findroot-fails-to-find-a-solution#comment596740_236291):

```
res = Check[
  FindRoot[{x^2 + 1 == 0}, {x, -1, 1}], $Failed[Evaluate@$MessageList]]
```

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.
>
> ```
> (*  $Failed[{FindRoot::cvmit}]  *)
> ```

Some ways to query the result `res`

```
FreeQ[res, $Failed]   (* True => success *)
```

> ```
> (*  False  *)
> ```

```
FreeQ[res, "cvmit"]   (* False => "cvmit" message occurred *)
```

> ```
> (*  False  *)
> ```

```
FreeQ[res, FindRoot]  (* False => message(s) from FindRoot occurred *)
```

> ```
> (*  False  *)
> ```

The structure of `res`, which is obscured by the standard output form:

```
FullForm[res]
```

> ```
> (*  $Failed[List[HoldForm[MessageName[FindRoot, "cvmit"]]]]  *)
> ```